# Google not supporting cancelling of consent on Oauth flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-denied

We have a use case where we want to check the number of users who cancelled the Oauth flow when the google Oauth flow shows up.
When the user is shown the Oauth flow, the user does not see any cancel option or anything with respect user **not accepting the consent**, or even being able to change the scopes permissions. Is it an accepted behavior or I am missing something?. The only way I can think of is on the front end, we can know if the user closed the browser tab, but I think that will not be a good experience for the user.

**For Facebook Oauth**:
The user is directed to the redirect_uri with the error message. I was expecting a similar experience for google since both follow Oauth2.0, or maybe I am missing anything here.

Reference for [Facebook_oauth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)